# docker install fails : File has unexpected size (9051 != 7889). Mirror sync in progress?

Tags: package-management, docker

typically this just works ... now docker install onto ubuntu 18.04 fails with

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
OK
sudo add-apt-repository \
>    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
>    $(lsb_release -cs) \
>    stable"
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Get:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease [64.4 kB]                                                      
Hit:3 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                          
Hit:4 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                   
Hit:5 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease      
Get:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages [7889 B] 
Err:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (9051 != 7889). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 99.86.58.71 443]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:7889 [weak]
   - SHA512:db24e63e6f882530d40047cda5c5cb43a9fd6936d518162135b59f315d9cf0e189453bddd8ee67ed0ef622012da02ecfd5f4e3419cfd116835651b37e4b6a7aa
   - SHA256:fed3e5b48da23965790e21466523ae19c1afe34f31e9005ac343e6b6a4c36d63
   - SHA1:f22380168007fac2e32b2d882a5120a288ed89e1 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:d35d55f528a96c383f4f3c1280cdd214 [weak]
  Release file created at: Sat, 17 Aug 2019 05:05:01 +0000
Fetched 64.4 kB in 0s (136 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/stable/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2  File has unexpected size (9051 != 7889). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 99.86.58.71 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:7889 [weak]
    - SHA512:db24e63e6f882530d40047cda5c5cb43a9fd6936d518162135b59f315d9cf0e189453bddd8ee67ed0ef622012da02ecfd5f4e3419cfd116835651b37e4b6a7aa
    - SHA256:fed3e5b48da23965790e21466523ae19c1afe34f31e9005ac343e6b6a4c36d63
    - SHA1:f22380168007fac2e32b2d882a5120a288ed89e1 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:d35d55f528a96c383f4f3c1280cdd214 [weak]
   Release file created at: Sat, 17 Aug 2019 05:05:01 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

using instruction from https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository

getting same error when using

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

evidently docker staffers are on it

https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/830#issuecomment-543930808